# My Camera following algorithm (Images included)

Tags: python

This was my old algorithm

```
def spawn(self):
    self.position_move() #to adjust when the player is spawned
def position_move(self):
    #gets called everytime the player moves
    camera.x = -object.x+Window.size[0]/2.0
    camera.y = -object.y+Window.size[1]/2.0
```

It worked well though when I approached a corner, I could see the 'outside' of the room.
[image]

The whole purpose of my updated algorithm is to prevent seeing the 'outside' of the room:

```
    def spawn(self): #when the player is first spawned
        self.position_move() #to adjust when the player is spawned

    def position_move(self):
            #camera.x = -(top left x corner of camera coordinate)
            #camera.y = -(top left y corner of camera coordinate)
             #room_size= total room (or world) size

        diff=(object.x-Window.size[0]/2)
        if diff<0:
            camera.x = object.x+diff
        else:
            diff=(object.x+Window.size[0]/2)-room_size[0]
            if diff<0:
                camera.x = -object.x+Window.size[0]/2.0
        diff=(object.y-Window.size[1]/2)

        if diff<0:
            camera.y = diff+Window.size[1]/2
        else:
            diff=room_size[1]-(object.y+Window.size[1]/2)

            if diff>0:
                camera.y = -object.y+Window.size[1]/2.0
```

My idea for the updated algorithm was to translate the camera back into the room by how much it is outside the room. Though my updated algorithm for some reason goes wonky sometimes (flies away, or doesn't even follow the player).

So yeah, it is a little complicated for what I thought was a simple task. Does anyone know the error is in my algorithm?

(The framework I am using has a coordinate system like this)
[image]

Comment: Not saying you should delete this question, but http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this kind of thing.

Comment: If the room is rectangular, you might be able to simply computer the upper and lower bounds of allowed center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the error in your code is (I haven't really looked), but here's a straightforward way of bounding the camera to the world:

```
# This assumes coordinates refer to the top-left of the desired viewport

# Since this is not the case, first invert the object's y to make it so:
object_y = room_size[1] - object.y

camera.x = max(0, object.x - window.size[0] / 2)
camera.y = max(0, object_y - window.size[1] / 2)

if camera.x + window.size[0] > room_size[0]:
    camera.x = room_size[0]  - window.size[0]
if camera.y + window.size[1] > room_size[1]:
    camera.y = room_size[1]  - window.size[1]

# Again, since you're using bottom-left coordinate system, invert the y:
camera.y = room_size[1] - camera.y
```

Comment: Many thanks Cameron. This problem burned my eyes for awhile (literally).